# How to check that VPN configurations(Settings) installed or not in iPhone device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, vpn

I want to check that if VPN is configured in iPhone device or not in swift. I'm here checking only for VPN configurations not for VPN connectivity.I'm able to check that device is connected to VPN or not.
Can anyone help in me how can I determine that VPN configuration is installed in device.Thanks in advance.

I have tried below code but this is not giving the correct solution.

```
let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()

func checkVPNConfiguration() {
    let isVPNInstalled = vpnManager.isOnDemandEnabled || vpnManager.isEnabled

    if isVPNInstalled {
        print("VPN configuration is installed on the device.")
    } else {
        print("VPN configuration is not installed on the device.")
    }
}
```